# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta SQL con parámetros?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, mvc, sqlite

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta de SQL con criterios de búsqueda, pero desafortunadamente no he conseguido que la consulta me traiga el resultado.

```
    public List<Persona> Listarwhere()
    {
        List<Persona> oLista = new List<Persona>();
        

        using (SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection(cadena))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            Persona obj = new Persona();
            Form1 idcliente = new Form1();
            //int cliente = int.Parse(idcliente.txtidpersona.Text);

            string query = "select IdPersona,Nombre,Apellido,Telefono from Persona where idpersona =@idpersona";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conexion);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@idpersona", idcliente.txtidpersona.Text));
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    oLista.Add(new Persona()
                    {
                        IdPersona = int.Parse(dr["IdPersona"].ToString()),
                        Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString(),
                        Apellido = dr["Apellido"].ToString(),
                        Telefono = dr["Telefono"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return oLista;
    }
```

Cuando realizo la consulta sin parámetros consigo traer los datos, pero si introduzco parámetros este no hace nada.

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar parámetros lo puedes usar asi
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$name", name)
Y en la consulta donde necesites el parametro pones esto el $name que coloscastes

comparto un ejemplo:

```
    insertCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Results(result, win) VALUES (@prizes, @win)";
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("prizes", prizes);
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("win", winAmount);
    insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: name con que valor lo igualo, como hago para darle un valor a name, debido a que el valor que quiero que lo consulte esta en una textbox

Comment: @Oscar2017 en la respuesta coloqué un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

''' public List Listarwhere(int idpersona)
{

```
        List<Persona> oLista = new List<Persona>();
        

        using (SQLiteConnection conexion = new SQLiteConnection(cadena))
        {
            conexion.Open();
            Persona obj = new Persona();
            ///Form1 idcliente = new Form1();
            //int cliente = int.Parse(idcliente.txtidpersona.Text);

            string query = "select IdPersona,Nombre,Apellido,Telefono from Persona where idpersona =@idpersona";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conexion);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@idpersona", idpersona));
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$name", obj.IdPersona);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

            using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    oLista.Add(new Persona()
                    {
                        IdPersona = int.Parse(dr["IdPersona"].ToString()),
                        Nombre = dr["Nombre"].ToString(),
                        Apellido = dr["Apellido"].ToString(),
                        Telefono = dr["Telefono"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return oLista;
    }
```

'''

la solucion radicaba en iniciar la clase Listarwhere con la variable que en este caso iba a realizar la consulta, despues de esto ya corrio sin ningun incomveniente la consulta.